# Why left shift 24 bits changed the value of unsigned long in C?

Tags: c

I expect `0b11010010 << 24` should be the same value as `0b11010010000000000000000000000000`.

I tested it in C, `0b11010010 << 24` doesn't work as expected if we saved it in c `unsigned long`.

Does anyone know how C unsigned long works like this?

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    unsigned long a = 0b11010010000000000000000000000000; 
    unsigned long b = 0b11010010 << 24;
    bool isTheSame1 = a == b;
    printf("isTheSame1 %d \n",isTheSame1);

    bool isTheSame2 = 0b11010010000000000000000000000000 == (0b11010010 << 24);
    printf("isTheSame2 %d",isTheSame2);
}
```

isTheSame1 should be 1 but it prints 0 as following

```
isTheSame1 0 
isTheSame2 1
```

Compiled and executed by `gcc main.c && ./a.out`

```
gcc --version
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

### Updated

As Allan Wind pointed out, I added `UL` suffix and now it works as expected.

```
    unsigned long a = 0b11010010000000000000000000000000UL; 
    unsigned long b = 0b11010010UL << 24;
    bool isTheSame1 = a == b;
    printf("isTheSame1 %d \n",isTheSame1);

    bool isTheSame2 = 0b11010010000000000000000000000000UL == (0b11010010UL << 24);
    printf("isTheSame2 %d",isTheSame2);
```

Comment: Also, compilers are very good at optimizations, like for example calculating compile-time values at compile-time. Which may yield different results.

Comment: ... UL (or ul) is the unsigned suffix.  0b11010010000000000000000000000000UL will fix the 2nd case.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There's no sign extension involved.  `0b11010010` is a positive integer constant (it's equivalent to 210).  Shifting it left by 24 results in overflow (assuming 32-bit ints).  If the shift operation ignores the overflow and behaves as an unsigned shift, then the result will be negative, but again, no sign extension.  Sign extension would occur when *right shifting*, in which case the sign bit is replicated in the high-order bits of the result.  Left-shifting into the sign bit, as is done here, is not sign extension.

Comment: Pedantically, as of present date, binary integer constants do not exist in C so there is no telling what type `0b1` boils down to. The rules for deciding types of integer constant only cover decimal and hex. Therefore anyone telling you to use `UL` are either just guessing or assuming that you are using a specific compiler extension. Binary constants will get standardized as per C23, though. Why, I have no idea, because typing out a whole 32 bits in binary presentation is madness, it is completely unreadable. (Even with new options for splitting them up in bytes/nibbles also coming with C23.)

Comment: Reference: [Allow for binary integer constants](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2549.pdf) discusses the proposed binary constants for [C2X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x#cite_note-N2549-27).  Such constants follow the type rules of a _hexadecimal-constant_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constant `0b11010010` has type `int` which is signed.  Assuming an `int` is 32 bits, the expression `0b11010010 << 24` will shift a "1" bit into the sign bit.  Doing so triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which is why you're getting strange results.

Add the `UL` suffix to the constant to give it type `unsigned long`, then the shift will work as expected.

```
unsigned long b = 0b11010010UL << 24;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a left shift of a signed value (see good answer of @dbush)

In absence of suffixes numbers have `int` or `double` types

```
b = 0b11010010 ;  /*  type int */
b = 1.0;          /*  type double */
```

If you want want b in your example as `unsigned long`  use a suffix:

```
b = 0b11010010UL;  /*  type unsigned long  */
```

or a cast:

```
b = (unsigned long)0b11010010;  /*  type unsigned long  */
```

Answer (score 0):

With 32-bit (or smaller) `int`, `0b11010010 << 24` is *undefined behaver* (UB).  It attempts to shift into the sign bit.

When `int` is 32-bit (common), this often results in a negative value corresponding to the bit pattern 11010010-00000000-00000000-00000000.

When a negative value is saved as an `unsigned long`, `ULONG_MAX + 1` is added to it.  With a 64-bit `unsigned long` the value has the bit pattern:

```
11111111-11111111-11111111-11111111-11010010-00000000-00000000-00000000
```

This large `unsigned long` in not equal to 0b11010010000000000000000000000000UL and so the output of "isTheSame1 0".

Had OP's `long` been 32-bit, it "might" have worked as OP had intended - yet unfortunately still replying on UB.

---

**Appending an `L`**

32-bit `unsigned long`: `0b11010010 << 24` suffers the same UB problem as above - yet might have "worked".

64-bit `unsigned long`: `0b11010010L` is also `long` and `0b11010010L << 24` becomes the value `0b11010010000000000000000000000000`, the same *value* as `a`.

**Appending an `U`**

32-bit `unsigned`: `0b11010010U << 24` becomes the value `0b11010010000000000000000000000000`, the same *value* as `a`.

16-bit `unsigned`: `0b11010010U << 24` is *undefined behavior* as the shift is too great.  Often the UB results in the same as `0b11010010U << (24-16)`, yet this is not reliably done.

**Appending an `UL`**

32 or 64-bit `unsigned long`: `0b11010010UL << 24` becomes the value `0b11010010000000000000000000000000`, the same *value* as `a`.

---

Since the left hand side of the `=` of the below is `unsigned long`, better for the right hand side constant to be `unsigned long`.

```
unsigned long b = 0b11010010 << 24;   // Original
unsigned long b = 0b11010010UL << 24; // Better
```